# Joining two networks together with a Mikrotik

Tags: router

I would like to join two networks together so I can access each device across both. I have a Mikrotik router I would like to use. Can anyone please assist in how to configure router to accomplish this. I have attached a diagram of existing setup.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K05Bw.jpg)

Comment: To start, you need 2 Mikrotik routers, if you want the traffic to be bidirectional. One on each side of the LAN's. Then you need to create 2 VPN tunnels.

Comment: Or add VPN routers at each end to make the tunnel. Microtik only works if it includes hardware VPN. The consumer Microtik I looked at was not a VPN router. Check that.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like EoIP tunnel fit your needs well. This is L2 link over IP so LANs behind both Mikrotiks will be able to communicate hosts at another LAN as if it is connected to each other.